# PUSH with jeroMQ

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

I think it is something wrong with my zmq.jar so I tried with jeroMQ but I have the same problem.

This is my method:

```
private boolean submitEvent(String ioMessage) {
    log.info("SEND");

    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context();

    ZMQ.Socket sender = context.socket(ZMQ.PUSH);

    sender.connect("tcp://localhost:8086");

    sender.send("MESSAGE");

    return true;

}
```

I have a script in python which is PULL and if I try a push script also in python, it receives everything.

So my problem is in java.

I see in logs the first line ("send") but I haven't receive anything in the script.

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Common mistakes](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/wiki#common-mistakes-already-mentioned-at-the-zguide-) at JeroMQ Wiki

- Close all the sockets properly otherwise `Context.term()` **will wait forever**

So your final code shoul be

```
private boolean submitEvent(String ioMessage) {

    log.info("SEND");

    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context();

    ZMQ.Socket sender = context.socket(ZMQ.PUSH);

    sender.connect("tcp://localhost:8086");

    sender.send("MESSAGE");

    sender.close();

    context.term(); 

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I checked the log and I found that the problem comes because of: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jeromq/ZContext but I don't know why because it is in the project

Comment: Yep, I had to change the route of my jeromq.jar I had to put inside project, not just add it to library path. Thanks man